# Having trouble with Random ore generation for minecraft 1.15.2

Tags: minecraft, minecraft-forge

So I am trying to make a minecraft mod that has a randomly generated ore. I have run into a problem in this part of the code.

```
import net.minecraft.world.biome.Biome;
import net.minecraft.world.biome.Biomes;
import net.minecraft.world.gen.GenerationStage;
import net.minecraft.world.gen.feature.Feature;
import net.minecraft.world.gen.feature.OreFeatureConfig;
import net.minecraft.world.gen.placement.ConfiguredPlacement;
import net.minecraft.world.gen.placement.CountRangeConfig;
import net.minecraft.world.gen.placement.Placement;
import net.minecraftforge.registries.ForgeRegistries;

public class ModOreGen {
    public static void generateOre() {
        for (Biome biome : ForgeRegistries.BIOMES) {
            if (biome == Biomes.BAMBOO_JUNGLE) {
                ConfiguredPlacement<CountRangeConfig> customConfig = Placement.COUNT_RANGE
                        .func_227446_a_(new CountRangeConfig(9, 10, 10, 0));
                biome.addFeature(GenerationStage.Decoration.UNDERGROUND_ORES,Feature.ORE.withConfiguration(new OreFeatureConfig(OreFeatureConfig.FillerBlockType.NATURAL_STONE, blockinit.chocolate_ore.getDefaultState(), 10)).withPlacement(customConfig));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Where it says `.withConfiguration` it gives me the error:

`The method withConfiguration(OreFeatureConfig) is undefined for the type Feature<OreFeatureConfig>`

I have already tried updating my mappings and such, but nothing helped. This has been a problem that has really irritated me for days now. What is happening?

Answer (score 0):

I just had this same problem with my code and finally fixed it. Try this out!

```
import net.minecraft.world.biome.Biome;
import net.minecraft.world.biome.Biomes;
import net.minecraft.world.gen.GenerationStage;
import net.minecraft.world.gen.feature.Feature;
import net.minecraft.world.gen.feature.OreFeatureConfig;
import net.minecraft.world.gen.placement.ConfiguredPlacement;
import net.minecraft.world.gen.placement.CountRangeConfig;
import net.minecraft.world.gen.placement.Placement;
import net.minecraftforge.registries.ForgeRegistries;

public class ModOreGen {
    public static void generateOre() {
        for (Biome biome : ForgeRegistries.BIOMES) {
            if(biome == Biomes.BAMBOO_JUNGLE) {  
                ConfiguredPlacement<?> customConfig = Placement.COUNT_RANGE
                    .configure(new CountRangeConfig(9, 10, 10, 0));
            biome.addFeature(GenerationStage.Decoration.UNDERGROUND_ORES, Feature.ORE.withConfiguration(newOreFeatureConfig(OreFeatureConfig.FillerBlockType.NATURAL_STONE,BlockInit.chocolate_ore.getDefaultState(), 10)).withPlacement(customConfig));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you elaborate a little on what you did differently and how did it solve it?

Comment: I'm still having the same problem. I would also like you to elaborate on what you did here.

Answer (score 0):

The obvious thing Sammerson did was to remove the strong typing  for CountRangeConfig: 
`ConfiguredPlacement<?>` , but that doesn't matter.

What you can't see is updating Forge to 1.15.2.

This is most likely your best fix.  In your build.gradle, somewhere near the top (mine is line 28) you've probably already updated your mappings to:

```
    mappings channel: 'snapshot', version: '20200409-1.15.1'
```

But you also want to go down and update the Forge version also (this is around line 90 for me).

```
    dependencies {
        minecraft 'net.minecraftforge:forge:1.15.2-31.1.0'
    }
```

You need to do the same

```
gradlew genEclipseRuns
gradlew eclipse
```

just like updating the mappings.

(You can check the Forge page, there may be a newer version than 1.15.2 by the time someone else reads this.  And I hope anyone using IntelliJ can figure out how to update your own mappings/forge.))

Comment: I have already updated my mappings. I will double-check and update again to the latest version. Is there any other reason it wouldn't work if I did update my mappings?